# OAuth third-party authencation status check

Tags: php, facebook, api, twitter, oauth

I have a implemented a basic log in system that uses known social networks(Twitter, FB, G+, etc) as its login providers, the login process is working just fine, but the problem is detecting the user's login status. For example, to make sure that the user is logged in via his Twitter account, I have to:

1. check for existence of OAuth token and OAuth token secret(both securely
   encrypted) within his local cookies as initial check.
2. If these cookies exist; I now need to make sure that they're both valid. So I have to request Twitter's API resource `/account/verify_credentials.json` and verify that the response's status code is `200 OK`(otherwise the user has invalid tokens)

So, as you can see, the second check is really *expensive* especially when I have do it on **every** single request, because - as an example - if the user is logged in there is no reason to display "Log in" button(which is in the header - the header exists in all pages)

Is there a better, standardized(across OAuth providers) way to check for user's log in status?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to make sure they are logged into Twitter to log into your system? They logged in with you via Twitter and you put the tokens (as cookies) into their browser. That should be good enough for you.